# Как понять данную запись с пайплайном ("|")?

Tags: javascript

Есть такая вот строчка кода: `(i / 3 | 0) * 10`. `i` принимает значения от 0 до 14. Как ее понять и, что более важно, можно ли (а если можно, то как) записать это более очевидно?

Для полного "Дзена" было бы еще неплохо получить хотя бы примерное представление о том, как она работает на примере двоичного числа.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53665/discussion-on-question-by-smellyshovel------).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Знак `|` является оператором "побитовое или".
`num | 0` не меняет биты числа как таковой, поэтому число `num` не меняется. Но в комментариях к вопросу было выяснено, что в JavaScript при этом отбрасывается дробная часть. То есть **суть данного выражения - приведение дробного числа к целому.** В данном конкретном примере берется целая часть от выражения `i / 3` (и умножается на 10, вестимо).

Также, наверное, стоит упомянуть про приоритет выполнения. У операции `|` приоритет ниже, чем у арифметических операций, поэтому скобки вокруг `i / 3` здесь не нужны.